# Regravação do registro no Banco de Dados

Tags: c#

Numa tabela de banco de dados com os campos ProdutoID, Descrição, PreçoUnitário e alguns outros. Tenho uma tela que permite somente a atualização do campo Preço Unitário, no momento de regravar o registro no banco de dados como deve ser a rotina para regravar. Fiz a seguinte rotina, porém o campo Descrição e outros da tabela foram regravados sem conteúdo.

```
ProdutoRepositorio app = new ProdutoRepositorio();

Produto produto = new Produto();

produto.ProdutoId = codigo;

produto.PrecoUnitatio = decimal.Parse(txtPrecoUnitario.Text);

app.Atualizar(produto);
app.SalvarTodos();
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você tem o Id do produto, basta buscar este produto dentro do método atualizar mesmo, ate por que já exite um método para isto que é o find:

```
ProdutoRepositorio app = new ProdutoRepositorio();

//aqui você usa sua logica para buscar o produto
Produto produto = app.produto.find(codigo);

if(produto == null){ } //entra se o produto não existir

produto.PrecoUnitatio = decimal.Parse(txtPrecoUnitario.Text);

app.Atualizar(produto);
app.SalvarTodos();
```

Comment: Perfeito Cassio, deu certo. Valeu. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo

Comment: Gilberto, marque como resposta

Comment: Perdoe-me a ignorância. Como marcar como resposta útil. Procurei mas não encontrei. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

no caso vc teria que puxar do banco esse dado e nao dar um new nele ja que vc esta atualizando o cara . Dai vc da um get no item e altera somento o que vc quer alterar com o input da tela e o resto fica oque ja estava no objeto retornado do banco.

mais ou menos assim .

var produto = app.find(idDoProduto)
produto.preco = valorVindoDaTela ; 
app.uptadeProduct(produto);

Comment: Ok. Vou testar. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Gustavo. Faço a consulta do registro em outro método (Leitura) e coloco dentro do var produto, conforme seu exemplo. Como posso fazer para dentro do método (Atualizar) ter acesso ao var produto. Obrigado.